# efficient way to copy array with mask in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have two arrays. One is "x" factor the size of the second one.

I need to copy from the first (bigger) array to the second (smaller) array only its x element.
Meaning 0,x,2x.

Each array sits as a block in the memory.
The array is of simple values.
I am currently doing it using a loop.

Is there any faster smarter way to do this?

Maybe with `ostream`?
Thanks!

Comment: Add your current code to the question.

Comment: Add your performance requirements to the question while you're at it.  This doesn't sound like an operation a sane application would be limited by...

Comment: A loop is fine, and the correct way to do this.

Comment: Thats what i eventually did. Improved a littel. hoped for something better. Thanks!

Comment: This is not what is called mask usually. What is called mask usually is when source and destination are totally aligned a la replace_copy_if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing something like this right?

```
#include <cstddef>

int main()
{
  const std::size_t N = 20;
  const std::size_t x = 5;
  int input[N*x];
  int output[N];

  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    output[i] = input[i*x];
}
```

well, I don't know any function  that can do that, so I would use the for loop. This is fast.

EDIT: even faster solution (to avoid multiplications)(C++03 Version)

```
int* inputit = input;
int* outputit = output;
int* outputend = output+N;

while(outputit != outputend)
{
  *outputit = *inputit;
   ++outputit;
   inputit+=x;
}
```

Comment: you could try to avoid the multiplication in the index calculation. and instead add a fixed offset to i instead. should make it a tiny bit faster

Comment: I didn't want to put what you say, because processor cost is similar, and it would not help too because [] operator always use multiplicactions, anyway if you want to optimize to the maximum, then use pointer arithmetic.

Comment: if the multiplication is a power of 2 arithmetic optimizers will reduce it to shifting anyway. I wouldn't be suprised if a proper optimizer wouldn't do a multiplication to do `[]`. in any case the op should benchmark his options. as we don't know what his compiler will do to the code.

Comment: @ronag I assumed that C++11 was not being used

Answer (score 1):

You can use [copy_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/) and [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) in C++11:

```
copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), b.end(), [&] (const int& i) -> bool 
{ size_t index = &i - &a[0]; return index % x == 0; });
```

A test case would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy_if

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(0);
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);
    a.push_back(4);

    std::vector<int> b(3);

    int x = 2;

    std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), [&] (const int& i) -> bool 
{ size_t index = &i - &a[0]; return index % x == 0; });

   for(int i=0; i<b.size(); i++)
   {
      std::cout<<" "<<b[i];
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Note that you need to use a C++11 compatible compiler (if gcc, with -std=c++11 option).

Comment: Does this really meet the requirements of "smarter and faster"?  Seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

if I get you right you want to copy every n-th element. the simplest solution would be

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const int size[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int out[5];
    int *pout = out;
    for (const int *i = &size[0]; i < &size[10]; i += 3) {
        std::cout << *i << ", ";
        *pout++ = *i;
        if (pout > &out[4]) {
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (const int *i = out; i < pout; i++) {
        std::cout << *i << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: just as a side note the branch (`if (pout > &out[4])`) might be expensive if it is a hot loop, but this is actually a loop invariant so it's movable to outside of the body and then adjusts the loop condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename InIt, typename OutIt>
void copy_step_x(InIt first, InIt last, OutIt result, int x)
{            
    for(auto it = first; it != last; std::advance(it, x))
        *result++ = *it;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 64> ar0;
    std::array<int, 32> ar1;
    copy_step_x(std::begin(ar0), std::end(ar0), std::begin(ar1), ar0.size() / ar1.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper and clean way of doing this is a loop like has been said before. A number of good answers here show you how to do that.

I do NOT recommend doing it in the following fashion, it depends on a lot of specific things, value range of X, size and value range of the variables and so on but for some you could do it like this:

```
 for every 4 bytes:
     tmp = copy a 32 bit variable from the array, this now contains the 4 new values
     real_tmp = bitmask tmp to get the right variable of those 4
     add it to the list
```

This only works if you want values <= 255 and X==4, but if you want something faster than a loop this is one way of doing it. This could be modified for 16bit, 32bit or 64bit values and every 2,3,4,5,6,7,8(64 bit) values but for X>8 this method will not work, or for values that are not allocated in a linear fashion. It won't work for classes either.

For this kind of optimization to be worth the hassle the code need to run *often*, I assume you've run a profiler to confirm that the old copy is a bottleneck before starting implementing something like this.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an observation on how most CPU designs are unimaginative when it comes to this sort of thing.

On some OpenVPX you have the ability to DMA data from one processor to another. The one that I use has a pretty advanced DMA controller, and it can do this sort of thing for you.

For example, I could ask it to copy your big array to another CPU, but skipping over N elements of the array, just like you're trying to do. As if by magic the destination CPU would have the smaller array in its memory. I could also if I wanted perform matrix transformations, etc.

The nice thing is that it takes no CPU time at all to do this; it's all done by the DMA engine. My CPUs can then concentrate on harder sums instead of being tied down shuffling data around.

I think the Cell processor in the PS3 can do this sort of thing internally (I know it can DMA data around, I don't know if it will do the strip mining at the same time). Some DSP chips can do it too. But x86 doesn't do it, meaning us software programmers have to write ridiculous loops just moving data in simple patterns. Yawn.

I have written a multithreaded memcpy() in the past to do this sort of thing. The only way you're going to beat a for loop is to have several threads doing your for loop in several parallel chunks.

If you pick the right compiler (eg Intel's ICC or Sun/Oracles Sun Studio) they can be made to automatically parallelise your for loops on your behalf (so your source code doesn't change). That's probably the simplest way to beat your original for loop.